# 'this' is null when working with onChange event on a reactjs check box

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am struggling with getting my react-js code update radio buttons when the user clicks them (or text input fields for that matter). First the code (slightly abbreviated):

```
// (...)
@connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
export default class EditMatch extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <input
                        type="radio"
                        name="ms"
                        value="isPlayed"
                        checked={props.matchStatus === "isPlayed"}
                        onChange={this.stateChange}
                    />
                    Not played
                    <input
                        type="radio"
                        name="ms"
                        value="played"
                        checked={props.matchStatus === "played"}
                        onChange={this.stateChange}
                    />
                    Played
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }

    stateChange(e) {
        console.log(e.currentTarget);
        console.log(this.props);
    }
}
```

The console output is:

```
<input type="radio" name="matchStatus" value="p2walkover" data-reactid=".109bqx8vjeo.0.0.1.3.1.2.0.1.2.0.7">
edit-match.js?6505:71 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
```

So basically 'this' is undefined. So I'm unable to follow [this pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27784932/507339) and call `this.setState`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the ES6 class syntax, your class' functions are not automatically bound to the proper context (like they would be when using `React.createClass`. [This is documented in the React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding).

You just need to update your onChange handler a bit:

```
onChange={(e) => this.stateChange(e)}
```

Or:

```
onChange={this.stateChange.bind(this)}
```

You can also change your class function definition instead, as per [the blog post](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding):

```
stateChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
    console.log(this.props);
}
```

Now you can call `this.stateChange` without prebinding it.