# React Radio Button event on "checked" attribute

Tags: reactjs, events, radio-button, checked

I'm trying to handle an event based on the 'checked' attribute of a radio button in React.js. I want the buttons to allow for selecting more than one value, so I removed the 'name' attribute which seemed to disallow multiple selections.

The base radio button component looks like

```
export function Radio_Button_Multiple_Selection (props) {
  return (
    <label>
      <input  type="radio"
              checked={props.form_data[props.field_name].indexOf(props.btn_value) > -1}
              onClick={props.radio_effect} />
      {props.btn_value}
    </label>
  )
}
```

I have a form_data objec that has an array of values that correspond to the btn_value of the radio buttons, where if the value is found in the array it should come up as checked. (And this part is working fine right now, they do in fact show up checked as expected):

```
const form_data = {
...
  occupations: ['student', 'merchant', 'paladin', 'troll'],
...
}
```

Now, I also have a react class with a method for manipulating the values in the occupations array,responding to whether the radio button being licked was already checked or not:

```
handleRadioButton (event) {
  const target = event.target;
  const value = target.value;
  const isChecked = target.checked;
  console.log(isChecked) // this undefined. why?!?
  if (isChecked) {
    // remove it from array
    // etc.
  } else {
    // add it to array
    // etc.
  }
}
```

My main issue is that following:

When I console.log the "checked" logic that returns a boolean inside the RadioButton component's checked attribute, it comes up as expected (true of false if it is or isnt in the array). But it always comes up as `checked = undefined` in the class method for handling the buttons.

Comment: are you sure you removed the item from the array?

Comment: I'm trying to gain access to the checked attribute in the event object first. that is what I haven't been able to do yet; or at least not correctly: I always get isChecked = true at the event handler method, even when I get false at the radio button component

Comment: Please try to !negate the value in the if-condition

Comment: Because radio buttons usually do not make an uncheck like checkboxes

Comment: I just noticed that event,target,checked is undefined in the handler; how do I access the checked attribute in event object?

Comment: there is also a post about this already on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784212/how-to-use-radio-buttons-in-reactjs

Answer (score 1):

You cannot uncheck a radio button in HTML either. You have to control the checked attribute with your props or state:

Even more, you should rely only on your state, instead of a mix, e.target.checked & state.

```
class Radio extends Component {
  state = {}

  render() {
    return <input
      type="radio"
      checked={this.state.checked}
      onClick={e => this.setState({
        checked: !this.state.checked
      })}
    />
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" />
```

Comment: I'm using redux, I dont want to use the local state, I respond to Store state received via props. I'm working with radio buttons based on this article: http://react.tips/radio-buttons-in-reactjs/ . Everything has worked fine with radio buttns for questions with single answers, but now Im trying to build a form that allows for multiple buttons selected at the same time.

Comment: Radio buttons are not the way to go if you have multiple items.. checkboxes are suited for that case

Comment: Oh! haha, didn't get that part. thnx

Answer (score 0):

I found the workaround:

use the 'value' attribute to store the same information that I am storing under the 'checked' attribute, with an array that has the button's value AND the checked logic boolean; e.g., value=[boolean, btn_value]

then access the 'value' attribute in the event handler. the value arrives as a full string, so I just split it at the comma and work from there.

it's hacky, but it worked.