# reactjs- checking/unchecking of radio buttons not working

Tags: reactjs

I have my below code. But the radio buttons are not checking or unchecking on click.

```
const Radio = props => {
  const { name } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        id={name}
        type="radio"
        name="type"
        value={name}
        checked={this.state.selectedOption === { name }}
        onClick={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
      />
      <label for={name}>{name}</label>
    </div>
  );
};
```

With a handleChange event handler.

```
handleChange = e => {
  this.setState({
    selectedOption: e.target.value
  });
};
```

I have defined the selectedOption in my constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    error: null,
    isLoaded: false,
    selectedOption: "",
    QuestionAnswer: [],
    counter: 0
  };
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784212/how-to-use-radio-buttons-in-reactjs, possible answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use radio buttons in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784212/how-to-use-radio-buttons-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `onChange` handler instead of an `onClick`
you can check my code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rr7okvlq54)

Answer (score 0):

By writing `this.state.selectedOption === { name }` you check if the `selectedOption` string is equal to a new object `{ name: name }` which will never be true. Check against the string `name` directly instead.

You also want to give your function to the `onChange` prop instead of the `onClick` prop.

```
checked={this.state.selectedOption === name}
onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updates in the below snippet

1)

```
checked={this.state.selectedOption === {name} }
```

to

```
checked={this.state.selectedOption === name }
```

**Corrections**

{name} means first thing destructuring {name:name}, you can read more about es6 destructuring [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). So you were trying to check whether the selectedOption is equal to name since there were two curly braces it means a new variable . Which is wrong you can directly check with `selectedOption === name`

run this snippet of code in console and check this

```
var a = 1
var b = 1
a === b // true
a === {b} // false
```

2) since you were using es6 no need to bind the method you can read more about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

```
  onClick={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
```

to

```
  onClick={this.handleChange}
```

```js
const Radio = props => {
  const { name } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        id={name}
        type="radio"
        name="type"
        value={name}
        checked={this.state.selectedOption === name }
        onClick={this.handleChange}
      />
      <label for={name}>{name}</label>
    </div>
  );
};

handleChange = e => {
  this.setState({
    selectedOption: e.target.value
  });
};

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    error: null,
    isLoaded: false,
    selectedOption: "",
    QuestionAnswer: [],
    counter: 0
  };
}
```