# Radio Button in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button

The problem i have is that the program is able to change the values from male to female but not the other way around.

The program displays a list of elements and this page has the option to delete those items. On editing the items everything is working fine, but when i try to change the gender from female to male, it does not change to and remains to be female.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Users extends Component {
  // call updateUser (App.js)
  handleUpdate = () => {
    this.props.updateUser(
      this.indexNum,
      this.name.value,
      this.age.value,
      this.gender.value,
      this.dept.value,
      this.occu.value,
      this.salary.value,
      this.daysWorked.value,
      this.leaves.value,
      this.message.value
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { allUsers, pressEditBtn, pressDelete } = this.props;

    const usersList = allUsers.map((user, index) => {
      return user.isEditing === true ? (
        <tr key={index}>
          <td>
            <input
              type="text"
              ref={val => {
                this.name = val;
              }}
              required
              defaultValue={user.name}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input
              type="number"
              ref={val => {
                this.age = val;
              }}
              required
              defaultValue={user.age}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input
              name="gender"
              type="radio"
              value="male"
              ref={val => {
                this.gender = val;
              }}
            />
            <label>male</label>
            <input
              name="gender"
              type="radio"
              value="female"
              ref={val => {
                this.gender = val;
              }}
            />
            <label>female</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>Department</label>
            <select
              ref={val => {
                this.dept = val;
              }}
            >
              <option value="HR">HR</option>
              <option value="IT">IT</option>
              <option value="Labour">Labour</option>
              <option value="BOD">BOD</option>
              <option value="Pantry">Pantry</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input
              type="text"
              ref={val => {
                this.occu = val;
              }}
              required
              defaultValue={user.occu}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input
              type="number"
              ref={val => {
                this.salary = val;
              }}
              required
              defaultValue={user.salary}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input
              type="number"
              ref={val => {
                this.daysWorked = val;
              }}
              required
              defaultValue={user.daysWorked}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input
              type="number"
              ref={val => {
                this.leaves = val;
              }}
              required
              defaultValue={user.leaves}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input
              type="text"
              ref={val => {
                this.message = val;
              }}
              required
              defaultValue={user.message}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input
              type="button"
              value="Update"
              onClick={this.handleUpdate}
              ref={() => {
                this.indexNum = index;
              }}
              className="btn green"
            />
          </td>
        </tr>
      ) : (
        <tr key={index}>
          <td>{user.name}</td>
          <td>{user.age}</td>
          <td>{user.gender}</td>
          <td>{user.dept}</td>
          <td>{user.occu}</td>
          <td>{user.salary}</td>
          <td>{user.daysWorked}</td>
          <td>{user.leaves}</td>
          <td>{user.message}</td>
          <td>
            <button
              className="btn white black-text"
              onClick={() => pressEditBtn(index)}
            >
              Edit
            </button>{" "}
            |{" "}
            <button className="btn red" onClick={() => pressDelete(index)}>
              Delete
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });

    return (
      <table className="striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Occupation</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Days Worked</th>
            <th>Leaves</th>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{usersList}</tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

export default Users;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deselect your radio buttons, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784212/how-to-use-radio-buttons-in-reactjs) by:

By explicitly specifying which radio button is selected, and in the onChange, unselecting the other ones, or

the other way is By grouping radio buttons together using "name" HTML attribute, which you have done, if the mentioned solution didn't work, I'll try to reproduce the issue