# How to use radio button on React with useState?

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, dom-events, use-state

I am stuck with this!

I have the follow code that I found here on Stack Overflow:
[How to use radio buttons in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784212/how-to-use-radio-buttons-in-reactjs)

I made some improvements to use arrow functions:

```
const App = () => {

    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        gender: '',
    });
  
    const setGender = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.value);
        setValues({ ...values, gender: event.target.value });
        console.log(values);
    };
  
  render() {
    return ( 
      <div onChange={setGender}>
        <input type="radio" value="MALE" name="gender"/> Male
        <input type="radio" value="FEMALE" name="gender"/> Female
      </div>
     )
  }
}

export default App;
```

I select the first radio and "MASCULINE" The result of the first Consolo.log is "`MASCULINE`"

-**BUT, the second console.log shows " `gender: ''` "**

When I select the second radio, without refreshing the page it shows:

-The result of the first Consolo.log is "`FEMALE`" and the second console.log " `gender: 'MASCULINE'`"

and if I switch to the first again:
-it shows me "MASCULINE" in the first and "FEMALE" in the second...

**AS IF THE STATE WHERE ONE STEP BEHIND**

How I can update the state in "Real Time"?

Answer (score 0):

The question here is why you want the state to be updated in "real-time"? What do you intend to do with the result?

`setState` is asynchronous in React because it allows improving performance. If you want to know when a state variable has been updated to perform an action (other than render because react takes care of that) you can use the hook `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
  // here, values has already been updated
}, [values]) //<- your dependency array, in this case values
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior. React triggers updates after your function finishes, so inside it you wont be able to see updated values

You could just move your console log out of that function and it would trigger once you do setValues.

If you need to have the value in "real time" then you need to use a ref (see useRef).

I made a demo for you so its easier to understand. Check it out [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-shpxyc)