# React component for radio button

Tags: reactjs

I have a form which contains many field of input and select.
I manage with the input and select but now I am trying to add radio button and textarea.
after the user pick an option the json I am sending isn't updating with the value came from the radio header also the checked attribute isn't updating when press.

this is the radio button component:

```
class RadioButton extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: this.props.options[0].name,
  };

  handleOptionChange = (changeEvent) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedOption: changeEvent.target.value,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { name, label, headline, options, ...rest } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <legend>{headline}</legend>
        {options.map((option) => (
          <div className="form-check">
            <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor={name}>
              <input
                type="radio"
                className="form-check-input"
                name={name}
                key={option._id}
                value={option.value}
                checked={this.state.selectedOption === option.name}
                onChange={this.handleOptionChange}
              ></input>
              <label>{option.name}</label>
            </label>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

this is my code for render radio button in the form:

```
  renderRadioButton(name, label, headline, options) {
    const { data } = this.state;
    console.log(name);
    return (
      <RadioButton
        name={name}
        label={label}
        headline={headline}
        value={data[name]}
        options={options}
      />
    );
  }
```

this is the call to render the radio button (this class derived form class):

```
  state = {
    data: {
      first_name: "",
      last_name: "",
      is_looking_for_job: "",
    },
    boolean_options: [
      { _id: 1, name: "Yes", value: "True" },
      { _id: 2, name: "No", value: "False" },
    ],
  };
          {this.renderRadioButton(
            "is_looking_for_job",
            "Looking for job",
            "Looking for job",
            this.state.boolean_options
          )}
```

I hope someone can help me.
thanks in advance!

Comment: you help this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784212/how-to-use-radio-buttons-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `class RadioButton` shouldn't be handling the selected value, that should be handled by the parent who creates the component and the value should be passed down as a prop.

Your RadioButton component should be updated to this:

```
class RadioButton extends Component {
  render() {
    const { name, headline, value, options, onChange } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <legend>{headline}</legend>
        {options.map((option) => (
          <div className="form-check" key={option.value}>
            <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor={name}>
              <input
                type="radio"
                className="form-check-input"
                name={name}
                key={option._id}
                value={option.value}
                checked={value === option.value}
                onChange={() => onChange(option.value)}
              ></input>
              <label>{option.name}</label>
            </label>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And it should be used like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    lookingForJob: "False",
    boolean_options: [
      { _id: 1, name: "Yes", value: "True" },
      { _id: 2, name: "No", value: "False" }
    ]
  };

  renderRadioButton(name, label, headline, options) {
    return (
      <RadioButton
        name={name}
        label={label}
        headline={headline}
        value={this.state.lookingForJob}
        options={options}
        onChange={(newValue) => this.setState({ lookingForJob: newValue })}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return this.renderRadioButton(
      "Name",
      "Label",
      "Headline",
      this.state.boolean_options
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is the problem:

```
checked={this.state.selectedOption === option.name}
```

change it to this:

```
checked={this.state.selectedOption === option.value}
```