# Need to populate value based on radio button input in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rxjs

I want to populate a value of text field based on radio button input for example if radio button output is yes then it will set text field value as "This is from yes" and if radio button output vale is no then it will set text field value as "This is from no"

Comment: Have you looked at into this question [How to use radio buttons in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784212/how-to-use-radio-buttons-in-reactjs). Some other helpful article [here](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-radio-buttons-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

This might help [react-native-simple-radio-button](https://github.com/moschan/react-native-simple-radio-button#readme)

```
import RadioForm, {RadioButton, RadioButtonInput, RadioButtonLabel} from 'react-native-simple-radio-button';
import { Text } from "react-native";


var radio_props = [
  {label: ‘Yes’, value: "This is from yes" },
  {label: ‘No’, value: "This is from no" }
];

export default class App {

  state = { textValue: radio_props[0].value} 
  
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <RadioForm
          radio_props={radio_props}
          initial={0}
          onPress={(value) => {this.setState({textValue:value})}}
        />
        <Text>{this.state.textValue}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please correct the answer vote up if it got helped :-)