# Can I decouple boolean state in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns

Like below simple react component code:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.c1 = this.c1.bind(this);
        this.c2 = this.c2.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            a:false,
            b:false
        }
    }

    c1(e) {
        this.setState({a:true, b:false})
    }

    c2(e) {
        this.setState({a:false, b:true})
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <input name="n" type="radio"  onChange={this.c1} />
                    <input name="n" type="radio"  onChange={this.c2} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    {
                        this.state.a && "aa"
                    }
                    {
                        this.state.b && "bb"
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The code simply switch displaying 'aa' or 'bb' while click the radio button. But if I add a new radio button showing 'cc' to achieve the same function. I should:

1. Add new state like 'c'
2. Add new input HTML and implement its callback
3. setState 'c' in this callback

All of those is ok, But I have to change the 'c1','c2' function that make my code coupling like:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.c1 = this.c1.bind(this);
        this.c2 = this.c2.bind(this);
        this.c3 = this.c3.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            a:false,
            b:false,
            c:false,
        }
    }

    c1(e) {
        this.setState({a:true, b:false, c:false}) // add 'c:false' which coupled
    }

    c2(e) {
        this.setState({a:false, b:true, c:false}) // add 'c:false' which coupled
    }

    c3(e) {
        this.setState({a:false, b:false, c:true})
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <input name="n" type="radio"  onChange={this.c1} />
                    <input name="n" type="radio"  onChange={this.c2} />
                    <input name="n" type="radio"  onChange={this.c3} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    {
                        this.state.a && "aa"
                    }
                    {
                        this.state.b && "bb"
                    }
                    {
                        this.state.c && "cc"
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I think this situation is very common in React. So I want decoupling my code no matter how many radio buttons I add. I do not need to change the code just add code to satisfy the 'Open Closed Principle'.

Do you have any recommendation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784212/how-to-use-radio-buttons-in-reactjs) might be what you're looking for (?)

Comment: thanks @DorWeid this is about design pattern not about how to use radio button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do like this

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.change = this.change.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            a:false,
            b:false,
            c:false,
        }
    }

   change = statename => e => {
    this.setdefault();
    this.setState({
        [statename]: true
      });
  };
  setdefault(){
    this.setState({
      a:false,
      b:false,
      c:false,
    });
  }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <input name="n" type="radio"  onChange={this.change("a")} />
                    <input name="n" type="radio"  onChange={this.change("b")} />
                    <input name="n" type="radio"  onChange={this.change("c")} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    {
                        this.state.a && "aa"
                    }
                    {
                        this.state.b && "bb"
                    }
                    {
                        this.state.c && "cc"
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way that you are storing the state as keyed `boolean` values doesn't feel right to me given that the properties are codependent rather than independent.

Right now, you have four options for `state`:

```
{ a:false, b:false, c:false } // initial state from constructor
{ a:true, b:false, c:false } // from c1
{ a:false, b:true, c:false } // from c2
{ a:false, b:false, c:true } // from c3
```

Based on your `setState` callbacks, no more than 1 property can be `true` at a time.

If each property was independent, you would have 8 options (2^3) and this setup would make sense.

As it is, I recommend that you instead just store which of the values is the one that is `true`.  You can check if an individual option is `true` by seeing if it matches the stored `selected` value.

You want your `Component` to work no matter how many buttons you have, so let's pass the button options as `props`. In terms of design patterns, this is "dependency injection".  We can create a `SelectOne` that doesn't need to know what its options are.  Here I am just expecting the `options` to be a `string` like `"aa"` or `"bb"` but you can refactor this to take an `object` with properties `label` and `value`.

We want to loop through the `array` of `options` and render each one.  Sometimes you see this extracted into a method of the component, like `this.renderOption(i)`, but you can also do the mapping inline inside your `render()`.

You aren't actually using the event `e` in your callbacks.  You could use the event to get `e.target.value`, assuming that you are setting the value property on your input (see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) regarding the HTML markup).  You could also pass the value to the callback by creating an anonymous arrow function for `onChange` which calls it with the correct value.  I'm doing that.

Here it as a class component, since that's what you were using previously.

```
class SelectOne extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected: undefined // this.state.selected will initially be undefined
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {this.props.options.map((optionName) => (
            <label htmlFor={optionName}>
              {optionName}
              <input
                type="radio"
                id={optionName}
                name="n"
                value={optionName}
                checked={this.state.selected === optionName}
                onChange={() => this.setState({selected: optionName})}
              />
            </label>
          ))}
        </div>
        {this.state.selected !== undefined && (
          <h2>Selected: {this.state.selected}</h2>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here it is as a function Component.  This is the newer syntax, so if you are just learning then I recommend learning with function components and hooks. Destructring the props makes it really easy to accept optional props and set their default value.  I'm allowing the `name` property of the `input` to be passed in here, but defaulting to your `"n"` if not provided.

```
const SelectOne = ({options, name = "n"}) => {
  // will be either a string or undefined
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(undefined);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {options.map((optionName) => (
          <label htmlFor={optionName}>
            {optionName}
            <input
              type="radio"
              id={optionName}
              name={name} // from props
              value={optionName}
              checked={selected === optionName}
              onChange={() => setSelected(optionName)}
            />
          </label>
        ))}
      </div>
      {selected !== undefined && (
          <h2>Selected: {selected}</h2>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Either way, you would call it like this:

```
<SelectOne options={["aa", "bb", "cc"]} />
```

You could also create a specific components for a given set of `options`, which you can now call with no props.

```
const SelectABC = () => <SelectOne options={["aa", "bb", "cc"]} />;
```

```
<SelectABC/>
```