# Reactjs: I am checking radio button based on state but can't click other radio button when one is checked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My radio button depends on value from state. If the user is Male, then value of the state is M and the radio button `Male` is also checked. Now say, I need to change it to `Female`. But, if I click on the `Female` radio button, it's not changing from Male.

This is my code:

```
// App.js
const [ gender, setGender ] = useState('');

return (
    <GenderComponent
        value={gender}
        name={"gender"}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    />
)

// genderComp.js
return (
    <div>
        <label>
            <input
                type="radio"
                checked={value==="M"}
                onChange={onChange}
                name={name}
            />Male</label>
        <label>
            <input
                type="radio"
                checked={value==="F"}
                onChange={onChange}
                name={name}
            />
            Female</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Save
    </button>
)
```

I want the radio buttons to check the field matching `value` and also those two should be editable. How do I do this?

Comment: You need to define your `onChange` function. There are many code samples on how to write radio buttons like this one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784212/how-to-use-radio-buttons-in-reactjs

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out `onChange` was working file. My issue resolved by replacing `checked` with `defaultChecked` and adding the `value` prop:

```
<div>
    <label>
        <input
            type="radio"
            onChange={onChange}
            name={name}
            defaultChecked={value==="M"}
            value="M"
        />
        Male
    </label>
    <label>
        <input
            type="radio"
            onChange={onChange}
            name={name}
            defaultChecked={value==="F"}
            value="F"
        />
        Female
    </label>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Joseph said you need to define the `onChange` function but  you also need to add the `value` attributes to both of your inputs.
By doing it this way, you can then use your newly defined function to operate on those values and store them in the state object. Updating the state would cause the component to update so you will see changes on your radio buttons as well.

I'll leave here the docs for the input radio button: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio