# I need to set radio button to select one at i time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What my task is I need to set the radio button to select one at i time right now what happening both are getting set at the same time net to set like if I select the frequency and after that, I select delta  then the frequency radio button get uncheck  but right now both are getting selected

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };
 <Row className="ISrch_Box_choices">
                      <Col className="IS_Radio_MediaQuery" lg={2}>
                        <label className="radio-mg" style={styleRR}>
                          <input
                            id="frequency"
                            type="radio"
                            name="frequency"
                            checked={value}
                            value="frequency" 
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            style={{
                              cursor: "pointer",
                            }}
                          />
                          <span style={styleRRB}></span>
                        </label>
                      </Col>
                      <Col>
                        <label for="frequency">Frequency</label>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row className="ISrch_Box_choices">
                      <Col className="IS_Radio_MediaQuery" lg={2}>
                        <label className="radio-mg" style={styleRR}>
                          <input
                            id="delta"
                            type="radio"
                            name="delta"
                            checked={value}
                            value="delta"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            style={{
                              cursor: "pointer",
                            }}
                          />
                          <span style={styleRRB}></span>
                        </label>
                      </Col>
                      <Col>
                        <label for="delta">Delta</label>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
```

Comment: You need `checked={value === "frequency"}` and `checked={value === "delta"}`

Comment: Duplicate: [How to use radio buttons in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784212/how-to-use-radio-buttons-in-reactjs)