# How can I actualize dynamic UI rendering on react through the radio buttons?

Tags: reactjs

Good day all,
I have two independent react components and I want to be able to render each by clicking on either radio buttons. How do I go about linking the radio buttons to their respective components? Thank you!!

Comment: use state, reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784212/how-to-use-radio-buttons-in-reactjs

Comment: Can you give a more detailed version of what you want? but as a generic answer: 
use state and pass the callbacks to the corresponding componet.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I saw some useful tips there to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use react state. if you're using hooks you can do

```
// defaulting this to radioOne but can be anything 
const [radioName, setRadioName] = useState('radioOne')

// then build a radio button and attach onClick event
<button onPress={() => setRadioName('radioTwo'}>Button Name </button>
```

then you can build another button for the other radio (or however many you have)

then build some rendering logic or whatever you want to based off that

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-router](https://reactrouter.com) to do that.